# VS2008 pro + seven pro 64bits

Tags: visual-studio-2008, x86, 64-bit

I recently installed W7 pro 64bits on my laptop, and then VS2008 pro with x64 compatibility.

If i build any project, will it be built with 32 or 64 bit compatibility natively?

And then, is it possible to change from 32 to 64 (or from 64 to 32) ?

'Cause most of my clients only runs 32bits applications, but I'd also liked to know how to build x64 application, and how to switch from one case to the other.

Thanks,

KiTe.

ps : sorry for my poor english ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define the solution configurations in Visual Studio you also define the possible platforms. What this means is that you can compile debug or release, x86 or x64 as desired.

To do this, open the configuration manager. At the top you will see a dropdown for "Active solution configuration" and "Active solution platform". On the platform dropdown, if x64 isn't present, select  and add x64 for 64 bit support.

Hope that helps.

Note, for C# in .NET, stick with "Mixed Platforms" and the program will run either 32 or 64 bit as the platform provides. You won't need to compile twice to get the support, the .NET framework will figure it out for you and run whichever is appropriate.

Comment: oh ok thanks, I found where to change it =).

One last question, just to be sure.
If I let the default option (any CPU), it will stick to what you said, right? (I mean compatibility with both x64 and x86)

Comment: Only if we're talking about pure CLR code for the .NET platform. This is easy with C#, not so much with managed C++.